# Show Exchange Calendar on MySite for All users

Tags: 2013, calendar, exchange

How can I make everyones MySite page to show their own calendar, and everyone can see each others calendar (Preferable just busy or not and not the whole title). Is there a way to do this automatically or programatically?

Ive looked at the Overlay Calendar feature, but that one can only show your own calendar.
And the Connect to Outlook feature only shows the SharePoint Calendar in Outlook.

Somehow, I want everyone to "expose" their calendar, and show it in their profile page.